# How to create a pending request list while allowing the promise to hang?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
class Network {
  constructor() {
    this.concurrency = 0
    this.pending = []
  }
  request(data) {
    if (this.concurrency <= 10) {
      ++this.concurrency
      return request({
        ...data
      }).finally(res =>{
        --this.concurrency
        this.pending.forEach(data => {
          this.request(data)
        })
        return res
      })
    } else {
      this.pending.push(data)
      return new Promise(...)
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to limit the concurrent request to 10, and let the excessive request to queue and return a pending promise until the concurrent request drop from 10...

Obviously the above code wouldn't work because `this.pending` is disconnected from the `new Promise`...

This is how I did it eventually:

```
class Network {
  constructor() {
    this.concurrency = 0
    this.pending = []
  }
  ajax = data => new Promise(resolve => {
    if (this.concurrency <= 10) {
      ++this.concurrency
      return resolve( this.send(data) )
    } else {
      return this.pending.push({ data, resolve })
    }
  })
  send = data => new Promise(resolve => {
    return request({
      ...data
    }).finally(res => {
      --this.concurrency
      if (this.pending.length)
        for (let request of this.pending) {
          request.resolve( this.ajax(request.data) )
          this.pending.shift()
        }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight.
1.) If request queue is less than 10, you return with the request promise
2.) Else, you return a promise which is resolved once the queue is less than 10 (ie. Promise which resolves to a request promise).

Or do you want a promise which resolves when it moves to the queue and the request is resolved?

Comment: I took a look at your answer I think it is what I wanted. Let me give it a try. @varunagarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Network {
  constructor() {
    this.concurrency = 0
    this.pending = []
  }

  async request(data) {
    if (this.concurrency > 10) {
      await this.queue();
    }
    // Make the actual request
    // Increment the concurrency count
    // call `this.next()` after success of every call
  }

  queue () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.pending.push({resolve, reject});
    })
  }

  next () {
    this.concurrency--;
    if (this.concurrency < 10 && this.pending.length) {
      let newReq = this.pending.splice(0, 1);
      newReq.resolve();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work...how would you write it in ES6 (ES2015) tho?

Comment: Take a look at my question, feel free to improve.